# Wordpress custom walker creating a double menu

Tags: wordpress, menu, jquery-isotope

Hello I have this custom walker set up for my wordpress theme to display my main menu.  I started tweaking it a month or so ago, but have since been working on some other bits.  Coming back to it, I am a little lost as to where I was when I left off.

The only real problem I can see at the moment is that the walker is generating a double menu.  So every link is shown twice.

Does anyone have any idea why the menu items are showing up twice?

Here is the custom walker:

```
class Custom_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {
        if ( $depth )
            $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        else
            $indent = '';

        extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
        $linkName = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->post_title, $page->ID );

        if($linkName=="HOME"){
            $output .= $indent . '<li id="item_'.$item->ID.'"><a href="#" class="all" data-filter=".all">'.$linkName.'</a>';
        }else{
            $output .= $indent . '<li id="item_'.$item->ID.'"><a href="#" class="'.strtolower($linkName).'" data-filter=".'.strtolower($linkName).'">'.$linkName.'</a>';
        }

        if($linkName=="CONTACT"){
            $output .= $indent . '<li id="item_'.$item->ID.'"><a href="/contact" class="contact" data-filter=".all">'.$linkName.'</a>';
        }else{
            $output .= $indent . '<li id="item_'.$item->ID.'"><a href="#" class="'.strtolower($linkName).'" data-filter=".'.strtolower($linkName).'">'.$linkName.'</a>';
        }
    }


    function end_el(&$output, $page, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
                $output .= "</li>\n";
    }

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you haven't learned how to use a if loop. You have two, hence two links will be output. You only want 1 to be output so:

```
if($linkName=="HOME"){
        $output .= $indent . '<li id="item_'.$item->ID.'"><a href="#" class="all" data-filter=".all">'.$linkName.'</a>';
} elseif($linkName=="CONTACT"){
        $output .= $indent . '<li id="item_'.$item->ID.'"><a href="/contact" class="contact" data-filter=".all">'.$linkName.'</a>';
}else{
        $output .= $indent . '<li id="item_'.$item->ID.'"><a href="#" class="'.strtolower($linkName).'" data-filter=".'.strtolower($linkName).'">'.$linkName.'</a>';
}
```